# Drag and drop between several lists

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have 4 lists of four different objects (A, B, C, D).

Is there a way to associate a name with each of these lists? In other words, list A being A, B being B ...

I intend to drag and drop an object and at the same time know which list it came from and where it went.

I used this to find out the automatically generated list value `console.log ("FROM" + event.previousContainer.id)`
    `console.log ("TO" + event.container.id)`, the problem is that these values ​​sometimes vary, they are not always the same and if you use conditions it can stop working.

Is there a way to assign or always get the same name from the list where it is object and the one in which it was dropped?

Thanks

**[Demo- Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4natzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**.ts**

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log("FROM" + event.previousContainer.id)
    console.log("TO" + event.container.id)
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `drop` function call this event data:

**For the previous container:**

`event.previousContainer.element.nativeElement.id`

**For your current container:**

`event.container.element.nativeElement.id`

---

Then in your HTML add an ID to the list element like that:

`<div ... #activeList="cdkDropList" id="list-A" ...>`

Comment: Perfect solution ! Thank you very much  !!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a list of elements and when drag and drop the element get add to the other list .

The easiest way to achieve what you want you need to add a key to each element in your list :

Keep in mind : **It's not the best solution**

Example :

```
A = [{
    name:"AA",
    belongTo: "A"
  },
  {
    name:"BB",
    belongTo: "A"
  },
  {
    name:"CC",
    belongTo: "A"
  },
  ];

  B = [{
    name:"RR",
    belongTo: "B"
  },
  {
    name:"PP",
    belongTo: "B"
  },
  {
    name:"QQ",
    belongTo: "B"
  },
  ];
```

HTML (div card-body for list A):

```
   <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;"  #activeList="cdkDropList"
      style="height:100%"
      class="box-list"
      cdkDropList
      cdkDropListOrientation="vertical"
      [cdkDropListData]="A"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[inactiveList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let nw of A" cdkDrag >
          <div class="card mysmallCcards">             
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>{{nw.name}} => {{nw.belongTo}}</span>         
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```